# Create Apex Map with List to use inside my LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-datatable

I'm trying to create multiple lightning data tables containing book records, organized by published date. The books in each table will have the same published date.

I am having an issue converting the returned map from apex into a usable object so that i can populate the data table.

I'm looking for help, and/or suggestions on how i can better convert the Apex map into a Javascript object, and then ultimately fill the tables with records. I'll leave notes in my code and towards the end of what I tried and what I am trying to achieve

**getBooks.apxc**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Map<Date, List<Books__c>> getBooks(Id recordId) {
   Map<Date, List<Books__c>> bookMap = new Map<Date, List<Books__c>>();
    
   List<Books__c> books = new List<Books__c>([SELECT Name, Author__c, PublishedDate__c FROM Books__c WHERE Genre__c = :recordId ORDER BY PublishedDate__c DESC]);
    
    for (Books__c book : books) {
        if (!bookMap.containsKey(book.PublishedDate__c)) {
            bookMap.put(book.PublishedDate__c,new List<Books__c>());    
        }
        bookMap.get(book.PublishedDate__c).add(book); 
    }
   
    return bookMap;
}
```

**BookComponent.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import GetBooks from '@salesforce/apex/BooksController.getBooks';

export default class BookComponent extends LightningElement {

  @api recordId;
  @api publishedDate;

  mainBookObj = [];

  @wire(GetBooks, { recordId: '$recordId'})
  loadBooks(books) {
    
    
    // I tried to reference books.data in my template iteration but I was getting a "e[Yn] is not a function" error. 
    // This is what I eventually got working, not sure if there is a better way?
    

    let tempBookObj = books.data
    for (var key in tempBookObj) {
      let value = [];
      for (var innerkey in tempBookObj[key]) {
        value.push({ key: innerkey, value: tempBookObj[key][innerkey] });
      }
      this.mainBookObj.push({ key: key, value: value })
    }
  }
}
```

**BookComponent.html**

```
<template>
  <template for:each={mainBookObj} for:item="book">
    <lightning-card key={book.key}>
      <lightning-accordion>
        <lightning-accordion-section name={book.key} label={book.key}>

         <c-book-datatable book-data={book}> </c-book-datatable>

        </lightning-accordion-section>
        </lightning-accordion>
      </div>
    </lightning-card>
   </template>
  </template>
```

**BookDatatable.js** (this is where im stuck)

```
 export default class BookDatatable extends LightningElement {
   @api recordId;
   @track bookList = [];
   @track columns = [{ Label: 'Name', fieldName: 'BookName__c'},{Label: 'Author', fieldName: 'Author__c'}];

   connectedCallback() {
     this.loadBooks(JSON.stringify(this.bookData));
   }

   loadBooks(taskObject) {
    const obj = (JSON.parse(taskObject));
    console.log(obj);      
   }
  }
}
```

**BookDatatable.html**

```
<template>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={bookList}
                columns={columns}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
</template>
```

Each iteration of the data table in BookComponent.html will give me an object with a key of the date and an inner array of the books of the same date. Which is what I want

I'm stuck in BookDatatable.js trying to figure out how to put that object in bookList which is the array on the data table that will hold the records. I think I need to iterate into the object somehow to grab the array of records.

I almost feel as if the object created from the apex map back in BookComponent.js was done incorrectly. Any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. First, `@api bookData` is not defined in your component controller. Second, you never assign the value to `bookList`. Until you get to some weird edge cases, I'd suggest you avoid this extra step anyways, and just set the list to the table directly:

```
export default class BookDatatable extends LightningElement {
   @api bookData;
   @track columns = [{ label: 'Name', fieldName: 'BookName__c'},{ label: 'Author', fieldName: 'Author__c'}];
  }
}
```

```
<template>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={bookData}
                columns={columns}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Sorry about that, it is actually defined in my component but I missed it when i copy and pasted it over. I get can't get the data to display in the table and I think it's because the object has an array inside of it. The array are the records I need to display in @api bookData. Appreciate all your help!